# how to convert cv::matND to string

Tags: c++, string, opencv, mat

I'm trying to convert a 3 dimensional matrix into string. I've tried other conversion methods on the web but they seem not to work for 3 dimensional matrix.
Any solution?
thanx

Comment: hey @DavidStutz
I have tried this code for saving it into a string:
`code`cv::FileStorage fs(".xml", cv::FileStorage::WRITE + cv::FileStorage::MEMORY);
        fs  << "mymatrix" << featureRefString1;
        string buf = fs.releaseAndGetString();
`code`
and this one for reading it back:
`code`
cv::MatND featureRefString2;
        cv::FileStorage fs2(buf, cv::FileStorage::READ + cv::FileStorage::MEMORY);
        fs["mymatrix"] >> featureRefString2;

Answer (score 0):

got the answer! the written function above works for N dimensional as well :D